# How to compare string char to struct array?

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

My goal is to turn a user imputed string to Tap code/Knock code.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_code

The problem i'm having is that i don't know how to compare the char i get from the string to the struct array.

I want to read a letter of a string then compare it with the structure array. 
So if i input the letter "a" the code will compare it with the array and output the corresponding row and column assigned to the letter, in this case 1 1.

What can be done to compare these two things?

Struct is mandatory here.

(New to programming)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct letter
{
    int row;
    int column;
};

int main()
{
    int x1 = 0;
    string input;

    letter a; a.row = 1; a.column = 1;
    letter b; b.row = 1; b.column = 2;
    letter c; c.row = 1; c.column = 3;
    letter d; d.row = 1; d.column = 4;
    letter e; e.row = 1; e.column = 5;

    letter f; f.row = 2; f.column = 1;
    letter g; g.row = 2; g.column = 2;
    letter h; h.row = 2; h.column = 3;
    letter i; i.row = 2; i.column = 4;
    letter j; j.row = 2; j.column = 5;

    letter k; k.row = 1; k.column = 3;

    letter l; l.row = 3; l.column = 1;
    letter m; m.row = 3; m.column = 2;
    letter n; n.row = 3; n.column = 3;
    letter o; o.row = 3; o.column = 4;
    letter p; p.row = 3; p.column = 5;

    letter q; q.row = 4; q.column = 1;
    letter r; r.row = 4; r.column = 2;
    letter s; s.row = 4; s.column = 3;
    letter t; t.row = 4; t.column = 4;
    letter u; u.row = 4; u.column = 5;

    letter v; v.row = 5; v.column = 1;
    letter w; w.row = 5; w.column = 2;
    letter x; x.row = 5; x.column = 3;
    letter y; y.row = 5; y.column = 4;
    letter z; z.row = 5; z.column = 5;

    struct letter arr[26] = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z };

    cout << "Input string using only small letters.\n";
    getline(cin, input);

    int length = input.size();

    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
    {
        do
        {
            x1++;
        }
        while (input[x] != arr[x1]); ////////////////////////////This

    }
}
```

```
1>------ Build started: Project: labwokrk4, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>labwokrk4.cpp
1>C:\Users\lietotajs\Desktop\corse work\labwokrk4\labwokrk4.cpp(62,29): error C2678: binary '!=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'char' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\visual basic temp\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\system_error(253,24): message : could be 'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\visual basic temp\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\system_error(248,24): message : or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\visual basic temp\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\system_error(243,24): message : or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\visual basic temp\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\system_error(238,24): message : or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_code &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\visual basic temp\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\exception(302,24): message : or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\visual basic temp\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\exception(298,24): message : or       'bool std::operator !=(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\visual basic temp\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\exception(294,24): message : or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &) noexcept'
1>C:\Users\lietotajs\Desktop\corse work\labwokrk4\labwokrk4.cpp(62,29): message : while trying to match the argument list '(char, letter)'
1>Done building project "labwokrk4.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Why does `k` have the same row and column as `c`? How will you tell the difference between the two?

Comment: @ron eye It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: presumably `arr[input[x]-'a']` will get you the right element without your `while` loop

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I want to read a letter of a string then compare it with the structure array. So if i input the letter "a" the code will compare it with the array and output the corresponding row and column assigned to the letter, in this case 1 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually no need to loop through the array to find the letter that matches. You can use character arithmetic to transform a letter from the input into an index of your Tap Code array.

That may look like:

```
for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
{
    if(std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(input[x]))) { // If it's not a letter, don't bother
        continue;
    }
    int indx = std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(input[x])) - 'a'; // Transform into index
    letter tap = arr[indx];
    // Do Tap Code stuff...
}
```

Comment: You need to cast your arguments to `isalpha` and `tolower`. Read the documentation.

Comment: @Asteroids why do they need to be explicitly casted?

Comment: You can read the documentation to find out. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha

Comment: @Asteroids I've seen the docs, but it's not clear to me why you believe this code won't work. Those `char`'s will be implicitly casted to `int`'s when they're passed to those functions. Can you elaborate on what you think is wrong here?

Comment: What value of `int` do you get when you pass a `char` of value `-25`? Always cast to `unsigned char` when using these functions, as the documentation says.

Comment: In this case it'll work but in general with non-ascii characters it won't

Comment: @AlanBirtles `input` is user-provided. You have no idea what it contains

Comment: Ahh I see @Asteroids. You're saying to explicitly cast to `unsigned char` first for safety. Just say so next time, instead of taking us on a wild goose hunt, silly :)

Comment: @scohe001 I did say to cast it. Then it's plainly stated in the documentation, in a big dedicated section, along with an explanation and examples; do I really have to do all the work for you ‍♂️